# How to run Spark standalone on Kubernetes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kubernetes

I have a Scala application that is using Spark 2.1 in standalone mode. The application will run for 2 hours and finish. It should be run once a month.

I found several approaches to combine Spark and Kubernetes:

1. Use Apache Spark Helm Chart: https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/spark
2. There is a special branch of Spark for Kubernetes: https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/spark
3. Build my own Docker image of my application including the Spark binary: http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/scaling-spark-with-kubernetes-part-5/ Code example: https://github.com/phatak-dev/kubernetes-spark

Most of the documentation describe how to run a Spark cluster on Kubernetes. What is the approach for running Spark standalone on Kubernetes?

Comment: "What is the best approach" - it's primary opinion-based. However second option has official ticket in Spark Jira and may be integrated into Spark

Comment: Thanks.
I did get the impression that purpose of special branch of Spark for Kubernetes is to run a Spark cluster without running Mesos.

Comment: I think you mean - "without running Standalone". That is correct. The special branch is for running Spark directly on Kubernetes. Details are in the JIRA and https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/34377

Answer (score 1):

For standalone spark on Kubernetes, the two canonical samples that exist are:

1. https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/spark
2. https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/spark

These are currently running outdated versions of Spark, and require updating to 2.1 and soon 2.2. (PRs are welcome :)).

The https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/spark branch is not for standalone mode, but aims to enable Spark to directly launch on Kubernetes clusters. It will eventually be merged into upstream spark. Documentation, if you wish to make use of it, is [here](https://apache-spark-on-k8s.github.io/userdocs/running-on-kubernetes.html).

As of now, if you want to use Spark 2.1, options are: either to compile your own image, or packaging your application with the spark distribution in [apache-spark-on-k8s](https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/spark)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Anirudh.
I am trying to make a minimal solution that just have Spark installed on a Pod without a running / demon Spark master with Spark workers. 
So I am reluctant to use Helm since that is solving problem of setting up a full working system.

Answer (score 1):

I first tried the simplest idea: Approach 3:

*Build my own Docker image of my application including the Spark binary: http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/scaling-spark-with-kubernetes-part-5/*

*Code example: https://github.com/phatak-dev/kubernetes-spark*

It worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Check my https://github.com/radanalyticsio/spark-operator

It deploys standalone spark on Kubernetes and OpenShift and supports also spark-on-k8s native scheduler. The default Spark version is 2.4.0

You can find the very quick start in the project's readme file, however here is a way to deploy the spark cluster using the operator:

```
# create operator
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/radanalyticsio/spark-operator/master/manifest/operator.yaml

# create cluster
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: SparkCluster
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  worker:
    instances: "2"
EOF
```

Comment: wow, why downvoting and mark for deletion? It's totally on topic.